# Repository not found error, right after `git remote add`

Tags: git, github

So I ran git remote add origin again to show that it already exists. The error looks self explanatory. How do I make `git push origin master` to work here?

```
(ENV)Benjamins-MacBook-Air:rss Ben$ git remote add origin git@github.com:ars/rss.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
(ENV)Benjamins-MacBook-Air:rss Ben$ git push origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
```

Comment: do a `git config -l` to see what your `remote.origin.url` is set to.  If it's not what you expect, you can `git remote rm origin` to remove it, and then add the proper url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather use the https form to push back to your repo:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
# in your case:
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/ars/rss.git
```

`git remote set-url` would *change* the url currently associated with origin (see [`git remote` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)).

Note that I don't have access to rss.git, so either you need to create it on GitHub first (and do a `git push -u origin master`), or it is an existing but *private* repo.

Note also that if remote origin already exists, you can keep it and add the github url under another remote name, like '`github`'.
Or you can *rename* the existing origin (`git remote rename origin otherName`), and then `git remote add origin gitHubUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

- Login to github.com as an administrator.
- Create the repository there with the same name that you used for the git remote add.
- If you're trying to push to a repository to a git account that you've been given access to, (like an account for your organisation) make sure you log in to that actual account on github.com, not your own.
- Re-try the push.